# Non-adjacent permutations

Tags: pr.probability, permutations, random-permutations

Suppose we have an $N$ by $M$ table.  Suppose that $x=(a,b)$ and $y=(c,d)$ are two locations in the table, specified by their row and column indexes.  We say that (x,y) is *horizontally adjacent* if $c=a$ and $d=b+1$ and *vertically adjacent* if $c=a+1$ and $d=b$.  Note that order matters; for instance, if $(x,y)$ is horizontally adjacent, then $(y,x)$ cannot be horizontally adjacent.

Suppose we permute the $N \times M$ cells of the table by some permutation $\pi\in S_{N\times M}$.  If there exists $(x,y)$ such that both $(x,y)$ and $(\pi(x), \pi(y))$ are horizontally adjacent, we say that $\pi$ is a horizontally adjacent permutation; similarly for vertically adjacent permutations.  If $\pi$ is neither horizontally adjacent nor vertically adjacent, we say that it is a *non-adjacent permutation*.

Let $f(N,M)$ be the probability that a permutation chosen uniformly at random from $S_{N \times M}$ is non-adjacent.  Can we estimate $f(N,M)$ as $N,M$ grow, or at least provide some non-trivial bounds?

For what it's worth, it's straightforward to produce a Monte Carlo estimate of $f(N,N)$; the credulous might believe that the following graph is converging to $e^{-2}$.

[image: Figure showing estimated probability of non-adjacency]

---

Judging by the comments, my problem statement seems to be a little confusing for readers.  Although my own reason for asking this question has to do with designing a statistical test, perhaps I can motivate it as a little game, which might clarify my intention.

We're going to play a jigsaw-puzzle-like game.  First, we take an image and divide it into $N \times M$ tiles:

[image: Image of Gauss divided into square tiles]

Next, we permute these tiles, being careful not to rotate or flip them:

[image: Scrambled image of Gauss]

Despite our scrambling, several of the pieces remain adjacent to each other:

[image]

This isn't as much fun to solve, since those pieces are already solved.  The probability $f(N,M)$ above is the probability that the puzzle is fun, i.e., has no adjacent pieces.

Comment: what does "permute the table" mean? Are you applying a permutation from $S_{N\times M}$?

Comment: If we look at $1$-D case on $S^1$ with $n$ points then considering $\pi \rightarrow \tilde \pi \times C_n$ (where $C_n$ is one cycle) then $\tilde \pi$ are derangements probability of which goes to $e^{-1}$ as $n \to \infty$. So, in 2D, if  the question asks about $\pi \times \pi$, then we get probability $e^{-2}$.

Comment: @kodlu Yes, I meant $\pi \in S_{N\times M}$.  I'll try to clarify the description a little.

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes, I plotted the $e^{-2}$ line because of the analogy with derangements.  But are you saying that the problem is actually *equivalent* to derangements in some sense?  I couldn't see how to make that work.

Comment: @BillBradley If only $x \rightarrow x+1$ on $S^1$ isn't allowed, then this is bijective to derangement just by shifting.

Comment: Ah, @AlapanDas, I think my problem statement may be unclear; let me add a more concrete example to my question...

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion should give a series which asymptotically matches an exponential series.

Answer (score 1):

Too big to comment, so I'm writing this here.

If we consider the $1$-dimensional circle ($S^1$) of length $n$, then the permutations $\pi$ which disallows $i \rightarrow i+1$ ($i \rightarrow i-1$ is allowed) then $\pi = \pi_D /C_n$ where $\pi_D$ are [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) and $C_n$ is an $n$-cycle. So, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\pi|}{n!}=e^{-1}$. This can also directly be proved using inclusion-exclusion. Moreover, if $i \to i \pm 1$ both aren't allowed, the probability of such permutations is $e^{-2}$ asymptotically. This can also be found similarly.

For the case in the question ($T^2 \cong S^1 \times S^1$), we consider $S_X$ as the set of all permutations s.t $X=(x,y) \to (x+1, y)$ or $(x,y+1)$.

Then $|\cup_{X} S_X| =\sum_{X} |S_X|-\sum_{[X_1,X_2]} |S_{X_1} \cap S_{X_2}| + \sum_{[X_1,X_2, X_3]} |S_{X_1} \cap S_{X_2} \cap S_{X_3}|-....$

Now, $|S_X|=2(n_0-1)!$ for the two cases. $|S_{X_1} \cap S_{X_2}|=4(n-2)!$ when $X_2 \neq X_1+ \hat {x}$ or $X_1 + \hat{y}$ or the other way (modulo $N$ or $M$), here $n_0=NM$. If $X_2 = X_1+ \hat {x}$, then instead it is $3(n_0-2)!$.

So asymptotically, the number of non-adjacent permutations is $D_{N, M} \approx n_0![1-\frac{2}{1!}+\frac{2^2}{2!}-...+ O(\frac{1}{n})]$, implying the probability to be $e^{-2}$.